# Angular *ngFor doesnt update list on add/delete

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ngfor

I have an app where I have a list of vehicles. I have a local .json file where I get my data. This data is updated with a web-api. Whenever I add a vehicle to the list it is updated in the .json file, but I have to refresh the web browser to see the updated result. It works in the same way when I am trying to delete a vehicle from the list. I use one local list to get quick returns and then I use a second list to make sure that the changes are saved to the .json file. See code below.

## Typescript

```
  // component
  vehicle: VehicleDetail;
  favVehicles: VehicleDetail[] = [];    
  favVehiclesLocal: VehicleDetail[] = [];

 ngOnInit() {
   this.vehicleService.getFavourite().subscribe(data => {
   this.favVehicles = data;
   this.favVehiclesLocal = [...data];
     });
    }
   }


 // Button function which adds the selected vehicle to your favourites
 addFav(event: VehicleDetail): VehicleDetail[] {
     this.favVehiclesLocal = [this.vehicle, ...this.favVehiclesLocal];
     console.log(this.favVehiclesLocal);
     this.vehicleService.addVehicle(event).subscribe(data => {
       event = data;
     });
     return this.favVehiclesLocal;
   }
 // Button function which deletes the selected vehicle from your favourites
 deleteFav(event: VehicleDetail): VehicleDetail[] {
       this.favVehiclesLocal = this.favVehiclesLocal.filter(h => h !== event);
       this.vehicleService.deleteVehicle(event).subscribe(data => {
         this.favVehicles = this.favVehicles.filter(h => h !== event);
         event = data;
       });
       return this.favVehiclesLocal;
     }
    console.log(this.favVehiclesLocal);
  }
```

---

The data is coming from a database and I use the following services to call for the data.

```
// Service for "add to favourite" button
  addVehicle(vehicle: VehicleDetail): Observable<VehicleDetail> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/favourites`;
    const service = this.http
      .post<VehicleDetail>(url, vehicle, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`adding vehicle id=${vehicle.id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<VehicleDetail>('addVehicle'))
      );
    console.log(service);
    return service;
  }

  // Service for "delete from favourite" button
  deleteVehicle(vehicle: VehicleDetail): Observable<VehicleDetail> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/favourites`;
    const service = this.http
      .put<VehicleDetail>(url, vehicle, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`deleted vehicle id=${vehicle.id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<VehicleDetail>('deleteVehicle'))
      );
    console.log(service);
    return service;
  }
```

## Html

```
 <!-- list of vehicles -->
        <aside *ngIf="favVehiclesLocal" class="vehiclelist">
            <mat-nav-list matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
                <th mat-sort-header="timestamp">Time of alarms</th>
                <th mat-sort-header="status">Severity of status</th>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let stuff of favVehiclesLocal" class="vehicles">
                    <span [ngClass]="getColors(stuff)"></span>
                    <p matLine (click)="updateInfo(stuff.id)"> {{ stuff.name }} </p>
                    <button mat-icon-button id="btn" *ngIf='check(stuff.alarm)' matTooltip="{{stuff.alarm[tooltipIndex(stuff)]?.timestamp}} - {{stuff.alarm[tooltipIndex(stuff)]?.description}}">
                        <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </aside>

// add and delete buttons
 <div class="details">
            <button mat-raised-button #add (click)="addFav(vehicle)">Add to favourite</button>
            <button mat-raised-button #delete (click)="deleteFav(vehicle)">Remove from favourite</button>
        </div>
```

What is going wrong here? I have been checking out the Tour of Heroes on Angulario ( https://stackblitz.com/angular/akeyovpqapx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts ) at .src/app/heroes/ and I havent been able to see a difference in their code and my code.

If you want me to clearify something or if you would like additional information please let me know.

## Update

It should be mentioned that I have two views. These views are either the full list or the "my favourite" list. The lists are displayed depending on the value of a slide-toggle.

In my code above I wrote *ngFor="let stuff of favVehiclesLocal" to hide unknown parts of my code since I thought I had the problem narrowed down. The complete app uses a slightly different approach.

```
 //app.component.html
 <!-- list of vehicles -->
        <aside *ngIf=".........
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let stuff of sortedVehicles" class="vehicles">

                    .........
        </aside>
```

The sortedVehicles is assigned in the following way:

```
 //app.component.html
 <mat-slide-toggle (change)="myFavourite(favVehiclesLocal)">Show favourites</mat-slide-toggle>
```

---

```
// app.component.ts
myFavourite(vehicles: VehicleDetail[]): VehicleDetail[] {
    this.toggleChecked = !this.toggleChecked;
    console.log(this.toggleChecked);
    if (this.toggleChecked) {
      this.sortedVehicles = vehicles.slice();
    } else {
      this.sortedVehicles = this.vehicleDetails.slice();
    }
    console.log(this.sortedVehicles);
    return this.sortedVehicles;
  }
```

I start to think that this line of code start to complicate things? Is there any way that I can register the change? Is there any more effective approaches to it?

Comment: there are 2 add, addFav, addVehicle, which add are you talking about? And where do you pull data from json?

Comment: addFav is short for addFavourite, whichis my function inside my component. I am using a web api and my addVehicle is coming from my .service.ts. I will update the post.

Comment: Nothing is going wrong: the data is loaded from the JSON file, and held in memory. The application has no way of knowing that the underlying file has been updated. The difference between your code and the Angular example is that, in their code, they `push` the new item in the variable inside `add`

Comment: @user184994 I agree that the code is very similar but they dont work in the same way. When I press add or delete, I see the updates in my .json file, but I dont see any difference in the DOM. The Tour of Heroes doesnt use much fancy code, and still it seem to work. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Yes. Your code calls off to a service, and that servce updates the file. Angular doesn't actually know that the file has been updated. In contast, the Angular example doesn't update **a file**, it also updates **a variable** (your equivalent would be `favVehiclesLocal`) by pushing the new value into that array in the subscribe function. Does your `POST` request return the new list with the item added?

Comment: @user184994 I did some troubleshooting and I believe you are correct. I have updated my post since I believe there might be another part of the code that causes some issues with the program.